# How do I press back button and auto-open jquery dialog that was left open in a previous page

Tags: jquery, redirect, dialog, back-button

Just like what the title says:
How do I press back button and auto-open jquery dialog that was left open in a previous page?

In my application, There's a page(let's call it page A) that contains a button that opens a dialog. Inside that dialog, there's a link that redirects to a new page (Let's call it page B).

According to my customer feedback, users are annoyed when they press back button while they're on page B to go to page A, they have to click on a button to re-open the dialog again in page A.

Is there a way to open the dialog automatically?

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like the jQuery History Plugin and use anchor-based navigation. This way when the users click back the last url would be something like "prevPage.php#dialog=true" and the plugin would fire a hashchange event that you could use to re-open the dialog.

http://tkyk.github.com/jquery-history-plugin/